# AJAX load and return only limited amount of objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, count, return-value

I'm just starting using AJAX and I wonder if it is possible to specify the amount of objects that should be returned from an AJAX call.

For testing I created a JSON.db file from [here](http://experiments.mennovanslooten.nl/2010/mockjson/tryit.html).

My code looks like this(using Polymer web-component):

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <h1>Object-list</h1>
  <template is="dom-bind">
    <evo-object_list>
    </evo-object_list>
  </template>
  <h1 id = 'loadInHere'></h1>
  <button onclick = 'loadDoc()'>Load</button>
  <script>
    function loadDoc(){
      var element = document.querySelector('evo-object_list');
      element.loadDoc();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

**web-component**

```
loadDoc: function(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("loadInHere").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
   xhttp.open("GET", "db.json", true);
   xhttp.send();
 },
```

**JSON**

```
{ 
  "fathers" : [ 
    { 
      "id" : 0,
      "married" : false,
      "name" : "Ronald Taylor",
      "sons" : null,
      "daughters" : [ 
        { 
          "age" : 9,
          "name" : "Barbara"
        }
      ]
    },
  { 
    "id" : 1,
    "married" : false,
    "name" : "Kevin Lopez",
    "sons" : null,
    "daughters" : [ 
      { 
        "age" : 6,
        "name" : "Angela"
        }
      ]
    },
  { 
    "id" : 2,
    "married" : true,
    "name" : "Matthew Harris",
    "sons" : null,
    "daughters" : [ 
      { 
        "age" : 19,
        "name" : "Helen"
        }
      ]
    },
  { 
    "id" : 3,
    "married" : true,
    "name" : "Thomas Lewis",
    "sons" : null,
    "daughters" : [ 
      { 
        "age" : 16,
        "name" : "Michelle"
        },
      { 
        "age" : 8,
        "name" : "Dorothy"
        }
      ]
    },
  { 
    "id" : 4,
    "married" : true,
    "name" : "John Martin",
    "sons" : null,
    "daughters" : [
      ]
    }
  ]
}

etc.....
```

My file could be very long and I don't want to load the whole thing, is it possible to define which objects inside the file and how much should be returned. e.g only the first three fathers and then the next three after reclicking the button?

I just use JSON now for testing but could have other files which i don't know now.

Please provide only pure javascript answers I don't want to use jQuery

Comment: That should be a feature on server side (for example, when you call an API that supports paging), but since you fetch a static content you can only limit what you show as an HTML.

Comment: You can tell server from `JS` to set limit of content. Other than that i do not think it is not possible from client side.

Comment: your are pretty much using javascript to hit an ajax endpoint (pretty much a basic webservice) so that webservice should support pagination. Otherwise you get nothing, since with pure javascript all you can do is download everything each time and dump what you dont need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, this is mostly a feature that should be implemented on the server side, but to provide you some guidance the idea is to send a parameter from the JS side, for example:

```
// Note the limit parameter sent to the server
xhttp.open("GET", "db.json?limit=5", true);

// Note the page parameter sent to the server
xhttp.open("GET", "db.json?page=1", true);

// You can even set custom paginations!
xhttp.open("GET", "db.json?page=5&per_page=50", true);
```

An example of this implementation is the stack overflow questions list, note the parameters in the URL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest